# Texture Mapping - coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, coordinates

I was working through texture mapping and I found this example which I cant figure out completely and I am not sure if the answer I got is right. Can someone help me out here

Question:

[image: stack]

I thought the answer was: `bottom-right vertex (1,0), top-left:(0,1), top-right(1,1)`
Is my answer correct?
If not can you explain how the texture mapping work. (no C++ code needed in explanation...I just want examples similar to the one above).

EDIT:
I think top right is (2,1)

Comment: Hint: Which corner of the texture does the top right look like? And where does the texture look like the top left?

Comment: I DID NOT SEE THE MIRRORING EFFECT!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadrilateral consists of 2 triangles. The triangle on the left is the bottom-left half of the original texture. The triangle on the right is also the same image, except mirrored. If you look at the corners of your quadrilateral, you will easily understand the texture coordinates:

```
original texture:

mountain peak  sky
(0, 1)(0.5, 1) (1, 1)
+--------------+
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
+--------------+
(0, 0)         (1, 0)
grass          sheep

quadrilateral

   peak               grass
       +--------------+
      /              /
     /              /
    /              /
   /              /
  /              /
 /              /
+--------------+
grass         sheep
```

Therefore:

```
 (0.5, 1)             (0, 0)
       +--------------+
      /              /
     /              /
    /              /
   /              /
  /              /
 /              /
+--------------+
(0, 0)         (1, 0)
```

Comment: Shouldn't top left be (0.5, 1)?

Comment: @nhahtdh, you are right, I thought the image is skewed! Jay, the image is not distorted.

Comment: oh yee image is not distorted

Comment: +1 for the awesome ascii art!